# getElementById check multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement

I am trying to build a function that checks if all fields are populated, if populated then show div if not hide.

I can get this to work on one fields however i have then tried two ways of checking multiple.

**first**
if first condition met I then ran other condition checking second field nested inside the first... this done not work.

**second**
I passed in an array of ID's rather than a single... this did not work either..

I am left with a working function that only works if first filed is populated can anyone think of a solution to this or maybe i passed in my array incorrectly.

**My code**

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 10);

function myTimer() {

if(!document.getElementById('Email').value) { // I need this to pass if multiple id's
          var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("somediv"); //divsToHide is an array
            for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
                divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "hidden"; // or
                divsToHide[i].style.display = "none"; // depending on what you're doing

        }
    }
  else {
   var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("somediv"); //divsToHide is an array
            for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
                divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "visible"; // or
                divsToHide[i].style.display = "block"; // depending on what you're doing
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide the html also

Comment: Its just a basic form

Comment: Regardless of it being a basic form or not, having a *runnable* [mcve] helps  others generate solutions for you

Comment: Meaby you want to try something diferent, instead of making an interval, create event listener for change in the fields that you want to check! Also you can check multiple fields like this:
if(document.getElementById('Email').value.trim() != "" && document.getElementById('...').value.trim() != "" ){ hideDivs() } else { displayDivs()};
or if ([listOfInputs].filter(input => !document.querySelector(input).value || document.querySelector(input).value.trim() == "").length > 0) {showDivs()} else {hideDivs()}

Comment: @ithan Please don't post long code blobs as answers in comments. Extremely hard to read and just adds extra noise. Create an answer with it instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of the IDs such as

```
let idArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

You can iterate through an array using a `for` loop

```
for (i = 0; i > idArray.length; i++) {
    if (!document.getElementById(idArray[i]).value) { 
        // your hide logic
    } else {
        // your show logic
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this is what i tried but for some reason wont work

Comment: Are any errors being logged to the console when you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Make it so your function takes an argument of the element ID and the class Name you need to check for.

Also, never use `.getElementsByClassName()` ([read here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)). Instead, use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

And, you can use the modern `.forEach()` API of arrays and node lists (not in IE though), which is simpler than managing traditional `for` loops with indexes.

Lastly, use pre-made CSS classes instead of inline styling.

```js
// You just need to pass the ID and Class to the following line
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer([id here],[class here]) }, 10);

function myTimer(id, class) {
  // Set up these references just once and the rest of the code
  // will be easier to read
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  var divsToHide = document.querySelectorAll("." + class);
  
  // Instead of negative logic, reverse the if branches
  if(elem.value) {
    divsToHide.forEach(function(){
      this.classList.remove("hidden"); // Much simpler than inline styling
    });
  } else {
    divsToHide.forEach(function(){
      this.classList.add("hidden");
    });
}
```

```css
/* Use pre-made CSS classes instead of inline styling */
.hidden { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a const of all elements that need to validate. For example,

```
const elementIdsToBeValidated = ['name', 'email'];
```

You can also create validator functions that returns true and false based on input,

```
const nameValidator = (val) => !!val;
const emailValidator = (email) => !!email;

const validators = [nameValidator, emailValidator];
```

Then you can run your timer function,

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer(['name', 'email']), 10);

function myTimer(ids) {
  ids.forEach(id => {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    const val = el.value;
    const divEl = document.getElementById('error');
    const valid = validators.reduce((acc, validator) => validator(val), false);
    if(valid) {
      divEl.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      divEl.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
}
```

You can look at this stackBlitz example,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ie7ljf